# reinstalling ubuntu and purchased software via USC

Tags: installation

anyone know what will happen if we freshly re-install ubuntu and our purchased software via USC. will it gone forever and need to purchase back or no need?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To buy software you need to have an ubuntuOne account. This means you can restore purchased software even if you remove/reinstall Ubuntu.

To restore previously purchased software open the software center and go to `file->reinstall previous purchases` and enter your account information in the pop-up window.